# inline javascript to render text year

Tags: javascript, jquery, inline-code

I currently have a datestamp after a copyright statment I would like to have the year after the - to be dynamic is there a way to sub in some javascript to write the year in as it changes see below for what i am hoping for

1994-2015

1994-

Comment: Seriously! This question is 3 years old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use js date object:

```
var year = new Date().getYear();
```

As per the comment about this method being deprecated, you can also use:

```
var year = Date().getFullYear();
```

Comment: getYear() is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear

Comment: you need to instantiate the Date object before you can access child methods in the Object.

Answer (score 5):

True inline solution :

```html
1994-<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>
```

Comment: why document.write is considered bad practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @RichardGrant I rarely use document.write but I agree with the 2nd answer on the link, sometimes it the right tool for the job

Comment: I agree as-well, and you are using it correctly. I just thought i would mention the issues with it. Depending how the OP's framework is set up Document.write might not work as intended

Comment: thanks Black )ut that did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

*Edited for cross browser support*

```html
<span>1994-
  <span id='year'>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
      var current_year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
      var year_node = document.getElementById('year');
      year_node.innerHTML = '';
      year_node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(current_year));
    </script>
  </span>
</span>
```

This grabs the clients local time, if the users time/date is incorrect so will this year output.

Answer (score 0):

Grab your element and append the current year by using the .getFullYear() function.

```js
document.getElementById('years').innerHTML += new Date().getFullYear();
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="years">1994-</span>
</div>
```

Comment: hey that works great! thanks MDN

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)

```
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();
```